# Vector collects host metric and fails to write to cnosdb database:The application panicked (crashed)

Tags: vector, visualization, metrics, monitor, cnosdb

[Vector](https://vector.dev/docs/about/what-is-vector/) collects host metric and fails to write to [cnosdb](https://www.cnosdb.com/) database, the log as follow:

```
The application panicked (crashed).
Message:  begin <= end (34 <= 10) when slicing `mountpoint=/sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio,collector=filesystem,device=cgroup,host=cicd_ujv23.100020,filesystem=cgroup,metric_type=gauge value=0 1695122686073428698
host.filesystem_total_bytes,collector=filesystem,mountpoint=/sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio`[...]
Location: common/protocol_parser/src/lib.rs:235
```

I want to collect host metrics through vector and write them to cnosdb to build a visual monitoring.my vector configure as follow:

```
data_dir = "/var/lib/vector"


[sources.hostmetrics001]
type = "host_metrics"

[transforms.tf001hostmetrics001]
type = "filter"
inputs = ["hostmetrics001"]
condition = '.name != "filesystem_used_ratio"'

[transforms.tfhostmetrics001]
type = "remap"
inputs = ["tf001hostmetrics001"]
source = """
# # 与 Vector Log 类似，不同的是需要添加到 metric 的 tags 中，写入的 table 名为 metric 的 name 和 namespace（namespace.name），所以不需要指定 table 名

.tags._tenant = "cnosdb"
.tags._database = "hostmetrics"
.tags._user = "root"
.tags._password = ""
"""
[sinks.skhostmetrics001]
type = "vector"
inputs = ["tfhostmetrics001"]
address = "127.0.0.1:12006"
```

And I start vector,

```
sudo vector --config-toml   /etc/vector/vector.toml
```

the vector log as follow:

```
2023-09-20T02:53:47.849792Z  INFO vector::app: Log level is enabled. level="vector=info,codec=info,vrl=info,file_source=info,tower_limit=info,rdkafka=info,buffers=info,lapin=info,kube=info"
2023-09-20T02:53:47.862010Z  INFO vector::app: Loading configs. paths=["/etc/vector/vector.toml"]
2023-09-20T02:53:47.868310Z  INFO source{component_kind="source" component_id=hostmetrics001 component_type=host_metrics component_name=hostmetrics001}: vector::sources::host_metrics: PROCFS_ROOT is unset. Using default '/proc' for procfs root.
2023-09-20T02:53:47.868379Z  INFO source{component_kind="source" component_id=hostmetrics001 component_type=host_metrics component_name=hostmetrics001}: vector::sources::host_metrics: SYSFS_ROOT is unset. Using default '/sys' for sysfs root.
2023-09-20T02:53:47.885149Z  INFO vector::topology::running: Running healthchecks.
2023-09-20T02:53:47.885348Z  INFO vector: Vector has started. debug="false" version="0.31.0" arch="x86_64" revision="0f13b22 2023-07-06 13:52:34.591204470"
2023-09-20T02:53:47.885410Z  INFO vector::app: API is disabled, enable by setting `api.enabled` to `true` and use commands like `vector top`.
2023-09-20T02:53:47.927543Z  INFO vector::topology::builder: Healthcheck passed.
2023-09-20T02:53:49.046900Z  WARN sink{component_kind="sink" component_id=skhostmetrics001 component_type=vector component_name=skhostmetrics001}:request{request_id=1}: vector::sinks::util::retries: Retrying after error. error=Request failed: status: Cancelled, message: "h2 protocol error: http2 error: stream error received: stream no longer needed", details: [], metadata: MetadataMap { headers: {} } internal_log_rate_limit=true
2023-09-20T02:53:50.090529Z  WARN sink{component_kind="sink" component_id=skhostmetrics001 component_type=vector component_name=skhostmetrics001}:request{request_id=1}: vector::sinks::util::retries: Internal log [Retrying after error.] is being suppressed to avoid flooding.
```

and I check the cnosdb log,as follow:

```
The application panicked (crashed).
Message:  begin <= end (34 <= 10) when slicing `mountpoint=/sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio,collector=filesystem,host=cicd_ujv23.100020,filesystem=cgroup,device=cgroup,metric_type=gauge value=0 1695178427886213462
host.filesystem_total_bytes,device=cgroup,collector=filesystem,mountpoint=/sys/fs/cgroup/ne`[...]
Location: common/protocol_parser/src/lib.rs:235
```

why the cnosdb crashd?

Answer (score 1):

I think you must complete your source code.
Because the vector does not know where to get the data from.

```
[sources.hostmetrics001]
type = "host_metrics"
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice ! @iyeah Does this mean that the configuration information is incomplete? I followed the example given in [the official vector documentation](https://vector.dev/docs/reference/configuration/sources/host_metrics/#configuration). Can you give an example?

Comment: Sorry, I have not used Host metrics source and consdb. I checked the documentation and found no consdb sink. Since you want to use consdb, why use vector sink?

Comment: You can print it at the end of remap, or add a file sink safely. To ensure that logs can be collected. Then use http or socket to write to a sink that is not provided by the vector official website, such as mysql. :D